# "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL" after Link is tapped in UIWebView - Multitasking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I show an UIWebView inside an Application which sends it delegate methods calls, after it receives taps on links.
In the Delegate Method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

I catch those calls, process the link-urls and run

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:processedURL];
```

This works as intended, I end up at the right place.

**Problem Multitasking:**
if I get back into my app, which is still running in the background after it closed, it will again call the "webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest" with the same link, so I end up sending the user to the page twice. Is there a preferred way to avoid this?

**Solution:**

You guys are totally right, I did a quite elongated if-else to analyze the given URL, but not in all branches the decision could end up in there existed a "return no"... duh, totally stupid error ;)

Comment: In my app I don't see the same behavior you're seeing, where `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` gets called again after resuming.  Are you returning `NO` from that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the UIWebView so that when it reloads itself, it doesn't have a request pending. This is probably best done this way:

```
[webView loadRequest:nil];
```

But if that doesn't work, you can use:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
```

And of course you should be returning `NO` from this delegate method since you don't want the webview to try to load this content.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I'd suggest doing this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(openURL:) 
                                            withObject:processedURL 
                                             afterDelay:0];
    return NO;
}
```

This way the callback can return as desired, and in the very next runloop iteration it will call `openURL:`.